# jquery link failes to submit form in popup

Tags: jquery, forms, popup

Can anyone tell me why the following code fails to submit the form into a popup?
A click in link should submit a form into a popup

```
$(".myClass").click(function () 
    {
        var myVar = $(this).attr("rel");
        //$(this).closest("form").submit();


        $("#form_id"+myVar).submit(function() 
        {
            window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=700,height=550,resizeable,scrollbars');
            this.target = 'formpopup';
        });     

    return false;
    })
```

if i remove the popup option and have just the $(this).closest("form").submit(); it works.
But as it is it fails.
Any thoughts/suggestions?
There is no js error in firebug.

NOTE: at the moment we do not want to use modal windows - so please no modal suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually submit the form. You only bind a `submit` event handler to it. You can use [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) or [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to actually trigger the `submit` event:

```
$("#form_id"+myVar).submit(function() {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=700,height=550,resizeable,scrollbars');
    this.target = 'formpopup';
}).submit(); //Submit the form after binding event handler
```

Your commented out call to `submit` will occur before the event handler has been bound to the form, so it would never be executed.